# Silverlight Listbox design- change backgroundcolor of alternate row

Tags: silverlight, listbox

how to change listbox to set background color of alternate row diff...
e.g. 
Listbox having 6 rows
1st,3rd,5th row having "blue" background and
2nd, 4th, 6th row having "white" background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/14345.aspx

Comment: The link does not work anymore - can you put the solution into the answer next time?